# How to improve perfomance

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the following table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableABC](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FieldA] [nvarchar](36) NULL,
    [FieldB] [int] NULL,
    [FieldC] [datetime] NULL,
    [FieldD] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [FieldE] [decimal](19, 5) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I do two type of CRUD operations with this table.

1. `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TableABC] WHERE FieldA = @FieldA`
2. `INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableABC](FieldA,FieldB,FieldC,FieldD,FieldE)  VALUES (@FieldA,@FieldB,@FieldC,@FieldD,@FieldE)`

FieldA has a unique value, but there is no constraint in the table.

Currently there are **6070755** rows in the table. Along with data growing , performance is getting slow.
Any suggestion , how to improve perfomance ? How to make CREATE and READ operation faster ?

now i faced problem , that select and insert takes too long , sometime more then 60 seconds

Comment: Any indexes on the table ?

Comment: Add an index to fieldA if you don't have

Comment: Are INSERT operations really an issue here? Or are you really talking about SELECT? That's 2 very different problems.

Comment: The insert is never the problem without any indices and constraints.  Whath appens is liklely that the table is blocked thanks to a select running.

Comment: @Squirrel no indexes. Does it matter what type of field i am gonna use for index ?

Comment: create index on `FieldA` as suggested in comments and answer

Comment: I have updated my answer so it should do all you need, feel free to test it in a copy of your table. Alter column will take a while if you can aford id, but you will benefit from it a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Read up on SQL basics-  and Indices DEFINITELY are one. And if you have a unique value and no index on the field (constraint is irrelevant, unique index is good neough) - yes, that will get slower. SQL Server has to check the whole table.

So:

- Add a unique index to Field a.

Given your 2 statements and the little "FieldA has a unique value, but there is no constraint in the table." I assume you are trying to enforce unique values there by selecting first. This will slow you down.

Instead make the index, and then try/catch the non unique sql errors - WAY faster. WAY faster. The index will make the insert a LITTLE slower, but you can save on the very slow select you do not totally.

Comment: Note OP says INSERT is also slow, but I'd probably dispute that.

Comment: Nah, see, the insert may be slow because of the select blocking everything. Root cause likely is the slow select.

Comment: That's one of the reason I am disputing it. But it may be worth mentioning that indexes will slow down (non blocked) inserts.

Comment: @TomTom i was thinking  about to use non clustered index for FieldA. But i  am confused with FieldA type, it's nvarchar(36) and contains GUID values. Is it  ok?

Comment: "ok" as "it works" - yes. "ok" as "beginner mistake making things 50 times slower" - also true. NEVER do that unless you have a real reason. Especally not NVAR - VAR - means vairable lengh (but GUID's are anyway fixed) and N means Uniqcode, which is 20 times slower in comparisons than non unicode. Ah, NO. GUID's are NUMBERS and there is a special datatype for them.

Comment: @Z.R.T. Why do you store GUID value as NVARCHAR type? SQL Server has a type to store such value UNIQUEIDENTIFIER. It's fixed, 16-byte type. You can also think about such change as a part of performance/tuning activity.

Comment: This is fully based on your assumptions of how is that table used. How can you know that?

Comment: More experience than you? Real world experience. Starting WAAAAAAAY earlier than 2012...

Comment: @JacekWróbel i've changed FieldA type from nvarchar(36) to UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, as a result i have Table data space increased from 2461MB up to 2,942MB. Why has data space increased ?

Comment: Dude, this is a Q&A site, not a free consulting service. Question, answered, done. Another question? OPEN ANOTHER QUESTION. Full basic traihning? Read a book.

Comment: @Z.R.T. It's expected behavior when you do perform ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN to change the type of the column in this situation (NVARCHAR-> UNIQUEIDENTIFIER). Additional space is required for data conversion to the new type. You can reclaim space which was release data in old type by issuing ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[TableABC] REBUILD; This should reduce data space.